# Dspece showing another username in the top menu or doesn't logout

Tags: authentication, dspace

I installed Dspace multiple time on different windows servers. 
I worked perfectly but i faced a fundamental problem in user authentication.
When I register a new account, it was made correctly.
the main problem is on the login/logout process.
When i logged in, then would like to logout,after a short refresh, the header of the Dspace was not changed the user status and continue to display my username instead of login button. I notice that when the page refreshed manually , the problem was solved.
another problem is that when i try to login from other browsers, before authentication, I see my username or other username(unknown) on top of the page. 
Please inform me about the potential problems and solutions.

Comment: Your question doesn't provide enough information to give you an answer.  What version of DSpace are you using?  What User Interface (XMLUI or JSPUI)? What web browser?  It sounds like a possible caching issue (either in DSpace or your web browser) if refreshing the page manually works.

This behavior does not exist on the public DSpace demo site (http://demo.dspace.org/xmlui or http://demo.dspace.org/jspui/). So, it sounds like it may be a local installation problem or a bug that has been fixed in recent releases.

Comment: It would also be useful to know what log-in mechanism(s) you use - DSpace password log-in? LDAP? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

It's the navigator cache. It is harmless